# SQL Query error an expression of non-boolean type specified in a content where a condition is expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with this query? I am trying to do an innerjoin to a different database on the same server.

```
SELECT b.company, i.CONCOM, 
    COALESCE (SUM(CASE WHEN C.CATEGORY_ID = '30' THEN 0 ELSE t .LOGMINS END), 0) AS TotalWithoutNew, 
    COALESCE (SUM(t.LOGMINS), 0) AS TotalAllId
FROM helpdesk3.dbo.INQUIRY AS i
INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] As B ON 
    i.CONCOM, B.company
INNER JOIN TIMELOG AS t ON 
    t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID 
INNER JOIN PROD AS P ON 
    i.PROD_ID =  P.PROD_ID
INNER JOIN CATEGORY AS C ON 
    P.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID 
WHERE (DATEPART(yyyy, ESCDATE)  =2011)
GROUP BY i.CONCOM 
ORDER BY totalwithoutnew desc
```

Comment: Is there any error or unexpected result?

Comment: I hope the actual query does not contain a "space" character after `t` (`ELSE t .LOGMINS`) as it is visible in the question.

Comment: Sorry that was a formatting error - the query errors with Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. Line 3 in the query where I am running is Line 5 and 6 on this question. Query worked fine before I put the first inner join in!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first join

```
    INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] As B ON 
        i.CONCOM, B.company
```

has columns list instead of join predicate. You probably meant `i.CONCOM = B.company`.

The other problem might be in your fully qualified name of table tbl_companies. As stated in this [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875):

> To refer to a column, there are three choices: fully qualified, partially qualified, and unqualified. A fully qualified name (written as db_name.tbl_name.col_name) is completely specified. A partially qualified name (written as tbl_name.col_name) refers to a column in the named table. An unqualified name (written simply as col_name) refers to whatever table is indicated by the surrounding context.

Comment: @aF copied your answer and stole your credit. He does that, he tried to do the same to me. +1 from me

Comment: @aF Very funny, you deleted your answer for this question after i voted you down and wrote my comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182601/how-to-set-a-value-to-true-or-false-by-null-check-in-tsql/8182893#8182893

Comment: @t-clausen.dk that's true because it was like you said. But not here.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it this:

```
INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] As B ON 
    i.CONCOM, B.company
```

Ypu should have this:

```
INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] As B ON 
    i.CONCOM = B.company
```

Comment: Once again you steal answers !