# How to set a value to true or false by null check in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, null, expression

What is the right syntax to return TRUE if the field is not NULL and to return FALSE if it is NULL in TSQL?

```
SELECT -- here return TRUE if table.Code IS NOT NULL. And FALSE otherwise
FROM table
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 select case 
           when code IS NULL then 'false'
           else 'true'
        end as result
 from the_table
```

Comment: "return TRUE if table.Code IS NOT NULL"

Answer (score 12):

There is no true or false in mssql. You can use the datatype bit and consider 1 as true and 0 as false:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Code IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END as Result
FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

For fun:

```
SELECT 
   ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNULL(code,0),code),1) 
FROM table
```

Comment: I agree for fun, poor maintenance team.

Answer (score 1):

int's are cast into true, so:

CAST(ISNULL(int, 0) AS bit)

You can use Length(x) if its a string type